# Can you use a wild card as part of changing rent on two property groups in a turn?

Tags: monopoly-deal

In Monopoly deal, can you use a wild card as part of changing rent on two property groups in the same turn?

For example, at the start of the turn, I have already played (on the table):

- 1 blue property
- 1 red property
- 1 wild multicolor property (associated with the blue)

After drawing my cards, can I do the following?

- 1st move - a blue rent card, with 2 properties on blue (one of which is the wild)
- Free action - Move the wild card to red.
- 2nd move - a red rent, with 2 properties on red (one of which is the same wild)

Answer (score 2):

This is a legal play.  You can move a wild property between sets on your turn, including in between charging rents, and doing so does not require an action.

The only thing from [the rules](http://monopolydealrules.com/photos/instructions-front.png) governing property rearranging is the following:

> You can only reorganize your property collection on your turn.

From this we can deduce:

1. You can reorganize property on your turn, including moving wilds between sets.
2. It is not an action (the game's notion of "action" is playing a card, and moving property around does not require playing any cards from your hand).
3. There are not limits on how many times a turn you can rearrange property.

A proper view of the turn structure looks something like this:

1. [Can rearrange property]
2. Draw two cards (or five if your hand is empty)
3. [Can rearrange property]
4. Play card 1 (optional)
5. [Can rearrange property]
6. Play card 2 (optional)
7. [Can rearrange property]
8. Play card 3 (optional)
9. [Can rearrange property]
10. Discard down to 7 cards.
11. [Can rearrange property]